# Spring Data Gemfire - Reading locators from JNDI

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

I am trying read locator host and port information from JNDI whose value is in the format host[port],host2[port2].

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="locatorsJndi" jndi-name="locators/locator1" />
<gfe:pool id="locatorPool" locators="#{locatorsJndi}">
```

It seems Spring Data gemfire unable to identify locators correctly in this case. It is taking JNDI lookuped value string as one host and is appending port 10334 at the end.

```
Unable to connect to any locators in the list [**host[10334],host2[10334]**:10334]; nested exception is com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.NoAvailableLocatorsException:
```

But, if i pass host and port values as part of locators attribute as below, it is working as expected.

```
<gfe:pool id="locatorPool" locators="host1[port1],host2[port2]">
```

Is this an issue in Spring Data Gemfire?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to connect to any locators in the list "`host[10334],host2[10334]:10334]`";

The host/port, comma-delimited String from the Stack Trace message is not correct.

I gather your configuration of the GemFire Locators in your JNDI context is correctly specified as... "`host[10334],host2[10334]`"?

If so, then this boils down to the simple fact that *Spring Data GemFire* does not properly, or rather currently, handle SpEL expressions in the `locators` and `servers` attributes of the `<gfe:pool>` XML namespace element based bean definitions.

It does, however, handle *Spring* property placeholders, as in...

```
<gfe:pool id="locatorsPool" locators="${app.gemfire.locators}"/>
```

It is a rather long and complex explanation to understand why the current behavior is what it is, but certainly this could be improved.  So, I have filed [SGF-535](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-535).

> NOTE: I fixed a similar issue in the `PoolParser` when property placeholders were specified with the `locators` and `servers` attributes in [SGF-433](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-433).

To workaround this issue, you can do the following...

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="locatorsJndi" jndi-name="locators/locator1"/>

<util:properties id="applicationProperties">
  <prop key="locators">#{locatorsJndi}</prop>
</util:properties>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="applicationProperties"/>

<gfe:pool id="locatorPool" locators="${locators}"/>
```

Follow [SGF-535](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-535) for updates on my progress.

Sorry for the inconvenience,

John

Comment: Thanks John for your quick response. I tried your work around. I am getting following error now. It does not say much about why it is not able to create locatorPool.    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The connection pool "locatorPool" has not been created.

Comment: Hi @nagesh20- Can you update your SO post and paste the new Exception?  The code snippet I gave you should have worked without incident.

Comment: Just an update... I resolved/completed SGF-535 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-535).  Also, the SD team will be releasing SDG 1.7.6.RELEASE (Gosling SR6) and SDG 1.8.4.RELEASE (Hopper SR4) tomorrow, and changes for SGF-535 will go out in these releases.  Hopefully, you are using either a 1.7.x or 1.8.x.  If not, I recommend that you upgrade given SDG 1.6 and earlier are no longer supported.  If you have additional questions or comments, let me know.  Cheers!

Comment: Hi @nageshb20 - For your reference... here is a test class from SDG's test suite that illustrates the use of both Spring property placeholders and SpEL expressions... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.8.4.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/PoolsConfiguredWithLocatorsAndServersExpressionsIntegrationTests.java.  XML config file... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.8.4.RELEASE/src/test/resources/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/PoolsConfiguredWithLocatorsAndServersExpressionsIntegrationTests-context.xml

Comment: Thanks John. I shall check with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Since the underlying exception is `NoAvailableLocatorsException`, can you please try connecting to the locators from `gfsh` to see if that succeeds?

```
gfsh>connect --locator=host1[port1]
```

Comment: I suspect the Locators are fine since he says... "But, if i pass host and port values as part of locators, it is working as expected."  I can see that the Locators String is not correct.  Adding additional answer now.